# Move ArgumentParser into seperate file

Tags: python, argparse

I have an argparser that is getting very long. I want to move it into a separate file to keep my main script clean. Right now I have:

**main.py**

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test',
                    default=0.1,
                    type=float,
                    help='test')
# Many more arguments
args = parser.parse_args()
# My main code
print("Argument in my code:{}".format(args.test))
...
```

Is there a way to turn this into two files to keep my main file clean?

**main.py**

```py
import parsing_file
# My main code
print("Argument in my code:{}".format(args.test))
```

**parsing_file.py**

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test',
                    default=0.1,
                    type=float,
                    help='test')
# Many more arguments
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this yet? It should work, provided you properly `import` the argparser you've built from `parsing_file` (maybe write a function in `parsing_file` that invokes and/or prepares the argparser and then returns it, then call it in `main`)

Comment: Yes, though you will usually either wrap it all in a function that you import from the module and call from `main.py`, or you import the parser itself and call `parser.parse_args()` from your `main.py`. In general, modules that are meant to be imported stick as much as possible to defining functions and values, rather than interfacing with the external execution environment.

Comment: If I run the example above. I get the following error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print("Argument in my code:{}".format(args.test))
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you creating a function for the argparse worked.

Comment: You have to use `parsing_file.args`, or `from parsing_file import args`.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks @Green Clock Guy and @chepner for suggestions on how to solve this. They suggested turning the parser into a function and returning it to the main function.

**main.py**

```py
import parsing_file

parser = parsing_file.create_parser()
args = parser.parse_args()
# My main code
print("Argument in my code:{}".format(args.test))
```

**parsing_file.py**

```py
import argparse

def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--test',
                        default=0.1,
                        type=float,
                        help='test')
    # Many more arguments
    return parser
```